# Accessing Google Docs Templates through PHP

Tags: php, templates, google-docs, google-docs-api, zend-gdata

We have implemented an extensive Google Docs integration in our web application. Only now, we'd like to be able to use Google Docs' possibilities for templates. When (in GD) you select "create from template", you get a list of possible templates and you select one to start working on a document with that template as a basis.

I can't find how I could access such a list of templates myself, through the API. Does anyone know a way, or at least point me in the right direction?

thanks in advance

EDIT: I've found that templates show up in my regular file searches, so if I could distinguish between files and templates there, that would also be fine.